# Python Split on \t 'fooled' by text with )

Tags: python, split

I have some python code that downloads an amazon report, makes a byte object, and parses it in to individual lines by looking for the \n.    It mostly works good but a block of text seems to fool the line split.   It is getting fooled by the text at the (120ml)

Code

```
report = report_api.get_report(report_id=ReportID)
report_as_dict = report.parsed  # bytes object
pp.pprint(report_as_dict)
line_split=report_as_dict.split(b'\n')

for line in line_split[1:]:
   pp.pprint(line)
```

Sample from 'report_as_dict'

```
b'elete\tpending-quantity\tfulfillment-channel\tmerchant-shipping-group\nMenic'
b'on Unique ab Multi-Purpose Solution + abc Case, ONE 8 fl oz (120ml) bot'
b'tle\t\t012312VTS55\t0P-avac2A-38\t19.99\t\t2019-03-19 13:43:38 PDT\t\ty\t'

b'1\t\t\t11\t\t\t\tB00E3GXZJA\t\t\t\t\t\tB00E3GXZJA\t\t\t\tAMAZON_NA\tMigrat'
b'ed Template\nRed Barn Naturals Cat Treats,  6 pack\t\t0'
```

Sample of the split - It mostly splits properly on the \n but has one extra split around the text that was (120ml).  The `') bottle'` should be part of the line above

```
[b'Menion on Unique ab Multi-Purpose Solution + abc Case, ONE 8 fl oz (120ml'
b') bottle',
b'',
b'012312VTS55',
b'0P-avac2A-38',
```

Comment: There's no comma after the first line of the output. Is that a typo? If not, then they are actually the same string; the first line continues to the next.

Comment: `.split(b'\n')` works as expected on this data on `python 3.7.1`

Comment: oh crap...  Yeah I see that.  My failure was actually further down  on the mysql insert where I had an extra field.  '"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1").  I assume it was this field being split in to two.   Reviewing my code further and will revise this question.. maybe it is the + messing up the mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no actual extra split there. That's just `pprint` doing something confusing.

See how there's no comma between `...(120ml'` and `b') bottle'`? In Python source code, two bytestring literals with no other tokens between them get implicitly concatenated into a single bytestring. (This also happens with regular Unicode strings.) Try it for yourself:

```
>>> b'a' b'b'
b'ab'
```

`pprint` has decided that the first bytestring in the `split` output is too long to print on one line, so it splits it into two implicitly concatenated bytestrings. `split` didn't produce an extra split.

Comment: thanks.. yeah this was it, my issue that cause the columns to be off was actually an error in the data set I was being passed